# Excluding grep from process list

Tags: grep, ps, pid

I have cobbled together a command to return the process ID of a running daemon:

```
ps aux | grep daemon_name | awk "{ print \$2 }"
```

It works perfectly and returns the PID, but it also returns a second PID which is presumably the process I'm running now. Is there a way I can exclude my command from the list of returned PIDs?

I've tested it a few times and it appears my command is always the second PID in the list, but I don't want to grab just the first PID in case it's inaccurate.

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/367921/how-to-prevent-ps-reporting-its-own-process

Answer (score 30, accepted):

grep's `-v` switch reverses the result, excluding it from the queue. So make it like:

```
ps aux | grep daemon_name | grep -v "grep daemon_name" | awk "{ print \$2 }"
```

**Upd**. You can also use `-C` switch to specify command name like so:

```
ps -C daemon_name -o pid=
```

The latter `-o` determines which columns of the information you want in the listing. `pid` lists only the process id column. And the equal sign `=` after `pid` means there will be no column title for that one, so you get only the clear numbers - PID's.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Using "grep -v grep":
Just watch out that you may have a long command line including "grep" (Let's say somebody wrote a grep library=>  "-Llibgrep.so" or "-cp libgrep.jar". At least I would repeat the pattern : grep -v "grep daemon_name"

Answer (score 26):

You can use a character class trick. "[d]" does not match "[d]" only "d".

```
 ps aux | grep [d]aemon_name | awk "{ print \$2 }"
```

I prefer this to using `| grep -v grep`.

Comment: Heh that's a clever trick, I like it. I'm keeping things simple at the moment though while I'm learning, and `| grep -v grep` will be easier to understand when I revisit my code.

Comment: I am trying to understand how this [h]ack works. Could you please explain what you mean with `"[d]" does not match "[d]" only "d"`?

Comment: @Damian: The square brackets are *metacharacters* (delimiting a set of characters) in the search expression so the `grep` command won't match the `ps` output line for the `grep` command itself (what tak called "a second PID" in the original question). expression `a[xy]d` does **not** match text `a[xy]d` but it does match text `axd` or text `ayd`. Hence expression `[f]oo` matches text `foo` but not text `[f]oo`. I hope that is clear.

Comment: Okay, I was wrong about ARGV. This is just a regexp. Thanks.

Comment: Devilishly clever! Had to think about it for a moment -- thanks!

Comment: I'm also using the `-w`, matching only whole words, and not killing all `bash` with the `ps -axu | grep [b]a` :) The `ps...|grep -w [b]a` is safer.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but this also should work on any position of the grepped character: ps aux| grep "daem[o]n_name"

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick It does not work for example: `ps aux | grep [s]cript1` or `ps aux | grep [s]cript2`. The grep line is still shown. Could you help to comment about the solution ? Many thanks ! O_O

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick My fault. It seems the line is shown because of the previous searches.

Comment: On MacOS I had to use quotes, i.e. `ps | grep "[v]i"`
Example, `ps | grep "vi"` gave the following two lines: 
`will % ps | grep vi    
29698 ttys000    0:00.06 vi src/strings/main.cpp
29736 ttys002    0:00.00 grep vi`

whereas `ps | grep "[v]i"` gave just one line:

`will % ps | grep "[v]i" 
29698 ttys000    0:00.06 vi src/strings/main.cpp`

Answer (score 16):

Avoid parsing `ps`'s output if there are more reliable alternatives.

```
pgrep daemon_name
pidof daemon_name
```

Comment: Yay, finally process management makes sense now.

Comment: `pgrep` searches by substring while `pidof` by exact match - exaclty what I needed! thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The `ps -C` option is not universal on all Unix based systems but if it works on your systems.  Instead I would avoid grep altogether:

`ps aux | awk '/daemon_name/ && !/awk/ { print $2 }'`

No need to escape anything in single quotation marks.  `ps aux` will give you the full list of processes on most Unix based systems and `awk` is typically installed by default.

Answer (score 3):

Use `pgrep` to look for the pid of a process by name:

```
pgrep proc_name
```

With extra process name in the result (`-l`):

```
pgrep -l proc_name
```

Look for and display the process name (`-l`) and arguments (`-f`):

```
pgrep -lf proc_name_or_argument
```

The good thing about `pgrep` is that it will never report itself as a match. But you don't need to get the pid by `pgrep` and then kill the corresponding process by `kill`. Use `pkill` instead:

```
pkill proc_name
```

Specify the `SIGKILL` signal (`-9` or `-KILL`) instead of `SIGTERM` (by default):

```
pkill -9 proc_name
```

Look for the process name (`-l`) and arguments (`-f`), ask for confirmation (`-I`) before killing it by `SIGKILL` signal (`-9` or `-KILL`):

```
pkill -KILL -Ilf proc_name_or_argument
```

Notice that the `-I` option is only available on some versions of `pkill`, e.g. the one on the OS X Mavericks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using bash, you can also do this in the following manner by making use of `ps -eaf`

```
PIDS=$(ps -eaf)
PID=$(echo "$PIDS" | grep "process_name" | awk '{print $2}')
echo $PID
```

Comment: This Is needlessly complex. Why not simply call `ps -eaf | grep "process_name" | awk '{print $2}'`

Answer (score 0):

this line gives you back the pid (process id) excluding "grep"

```
PID=$(ps aux | grep '/usr/bin/python2.7 manage.py SES__boto3_sqs_read' | grep -v grep)
```

Comment: Some explanation would be nice.

Comment: This is basically the same as the accepted answer, but with different decoration.